# ArcGIS JS API 4.11, 4.12 Incorrect work GraphicsView2D (from esri/views/2d/layers/grapics/GraphicsView2D) hitTest method

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

ArcGIS JS API 4.11, 4.12
GraphicsView2D (from esri/views/2d/layers/grapics/GraphicsView2D) hitTest method return only one feature (graphic) with zero index.
Better to be return all graphics.

Is it issue or correct work?

UPD:
I opened source code https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources
Go to 4master branch
Open /views/2d/layers/graphics/GraphicsView2D.js

in hitTest method see implementation like

```
t.prototype.hitTest = function (e, t) {
        if (!this.view || !this.view.position) return l.resolve();
        var r = this.view.toMap(g.createScreenPoint(e, t));
        return this.searchFeatures(r).then(function (e) {
            return e && e.length ? e[0] : null
        })
    }
```

From all features from graphicsView return only one value (e[0] with zero index)

I created example https://jsfiddle.net/catcherholms/dmp1z387/143/ with many objects

[image: When I clicked here]

when I clicked here in hitTest result I receive one feature and should be more than one

Comment: You'd need to provide a full example in code with sample data to explain your meaning. But if it was a bug, then this wouldn't be the appropriate place to report it.

Comment: @Vince
Try open next example
https://jsfiddle.net/catcherholms/dmp1z387/142/

Change zoom to 5 and click on objects. In console you see only one object from hitTest but should be more

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain the code. External links aren't followed and fail over time.

Comment: @Vince updated description